# AngularJS code to query DB and update $scope

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, angular.js, database

I have an AngularJS function that is used to determine which `$scope` associative array variable is to have data pushed into it. I would love to be able to remove the switch case entirely if possible but haven't been able to envision a way to do that! *My overall goal is to both improve performance, but more importantly reduce the overall number of lines if possible*

I also considered perhaps some type of variable interpolation, but that seemed like an investment with little return on my effort.

The `ng-change` directive is called in my HTML like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="category-select-addon" style="width:110px">Category:</span>
            <select 
                    class="form-control" 
                    type="select" 
                    name="categories" 
                    ng-model="categorySelect" 
                    aria-describedby="category-select-addon" 
                    ng-options="category.name as category.name for category in categories"
                    ng-change="updateSelection(categorySelect, 'category')" required>
            </select>
        </div>
```

**AngularJS Code:**

```
 $scope.updateSelection = function(value, field) {
    $log.debug("Inside updateSelection");
    $log.info("Values passed in: (" + value + ", " + field + ")");
    switch (field) {
        case 'tool':
            $scope.tool = value;
            $scope.data = $.param({
                table: $scope.tool,
                tool : $scope.tool,
            });

            $scope.dbQuery($scope.url, $scope.data, $scope.config, $scope.type['category']);
            break;

        case 'category':
            $scope.category = value;
            $scope.data = $.param({
                table: $scope.tool,
                tool : $scope.tool,
                category: $scope.category
            });

            $scope.dbQuery($scope.url, $scope.data, $scope.config, $scope.type['subCategory']);
            break;

        case 'subcategory':
            $scope.subCategory = value;
            $scope.data = $.param({
                table: $scope.tool,
                tool : $scope.tool,
                category: $scope.category,
                sub_category: $scope.subCategory
            });
            $scope.dbQuery($scope.url, $scope.data, $scope.config, $scope.type['issue']);
            break;

        case 'issue':
            $scope.issue = value;
            $scope.data = $.param({
                table: $scope.tool,
                tool : $scope.tool,
                category: $scope.category,
                sub_category: $scope.subCategory,
                issue: $scope.issue
            });

            $scope.dbQuery($scope.url, $scope.data, $scope.config, $scope.type['script']);

            $scope.data = $.param({
                table: $scope.tool,
                tool : $scope.tool,
                category: $scope.category,
                sub_category: $scope.subCategory,
                issue: $scope.issue,
                flag: true
            });

            $scope.dbQuery($scope.url, $scope.data, $scope.config, $scope.type['workInstruction']);
            break;

        default:
            $log.error("Error case reached in dbQuery()! Couldn't find a query for case: " + field);
            break;
    }

}

$scope.dbQuery = function dbQuery(url, data, config, member) {
    $http.post(url, data, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {            
            var i = 0;
            switch (member) {
                case 'tool':
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $scope.tools.push({name: data[i]});
                    }
                    break;

                case 'category':
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $scope.categories.push({name: data[i]});    
                    }
                    break;

                case 'subCategory':
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $scope.subcategories.push({name: data[i]});    
                    }
                    break;

                case 'issue':
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        $scope.issues.push({name: data[i]});    
                    }
                    break;

                case 'script':
                    $scope.script = data[0];
                    break;

                case 'workInstruction':
                    $scope.workInstruction = data[0];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            var result = 'Bad query: ' + data +
                "<hr />status: "  + status +
                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                "<hr />config: "  + config;
            $log.error(result);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of repetition in the code.

`$scope.tool = value;` and similar after every switch can be replaced by single `$scope[field]=value;`

Every time a data object is created, which deserves to be outsourced in a dedicated service. So is the server request - NO `$http` inside a controller. Controller's responsibility is only to glue the data from services, not to do more.

`function dbQuery(url, data, config, member)` has way too many argument, a single object argument makes it more readable.

Also usage `controller as` is preferable.

Comment: HI Dimitri, thank you for the feedback! I have never heard of putting the $http outside the controller, could you please provide examples of the changes you are suggesting so that I can visualize what you are describing?  Also, I tend to disagree that 4 arguments is too many; their use is very easy to read and straightforward.

Comment: @EvanBechtol Search for Angular best practices and style guides, many examples there. Even 2 arguments make function hard to use because you have to remember the order. Bob Martin advocates 0 or at most 1 argument. What appears easy can become unmanageable as application grows. Do as it works for you but at your own risk :)

Comment: @EvanBechtol Check this Angular styleguide for where to put server requests: https://github.com/gocardless/angularjs-style-guide#store-presentation-logic-in-controllers-and-business-logic-in-services